# How to make the alert have the correct word?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have text in a TextView, there are some words in the text, in the case when the user clicks on it, an alert should appear with a word, which for example can mean a word translation into some language.

I tried to use a dictionary, where the key is the word in the text, and the word in the alert is a value. But it does not work. There is an alert with the wrong word.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextViewDelegate    {
    private let kURLString = "https://www.mywebsite.com"

    let dictionary = ["website" : "Johny" , "visit" : "Bilbo"]

    var keyOne : String?
    var valueOne : String?

    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView! {
        didSet{
            text.delegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let originalText = "Please visit the website for more information."
        let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText)

        for (key , value) in dictionary {
            keyOne = key
            valueOne = value
            let linkRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: keyOne!)
            attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(.link, value: kURLString, range: linkRange)

        }

        text.attributedText = attributedOriginalText    
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        if (URL.absoluteString == kURLString) {
            alert(value: valueOne!)
        }
        return false
    }

    func alert (value : String) {
         let alert = UIAlertController (title: nil, message: value, preferredStyle: .alert)

         let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ок", style: .default , handler : { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.viewDidLoad()
         })

         alert.addAction(restartAction)

         present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: in the alert function you have a parameter " value " that you don't use, and insted you use " valueOne"

Comment: Changed, but it did not help : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in text views are interactive only if the text view is selectable but noneditable.

set editable false & selectable true:

```
text.isEditable = false
text.isSelectable = true
```

To get selected text from textview which is key in your case use below function:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
          if let key = textView.text.substring(with: characterRange){
            if let value = dictionary[String(key)]{
                print("text :",value)
                alert(value: value)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Using extension for string to get Substring with range:

```
extension String {
    func substring(with nsrange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        guard let range = Range(nsrange, in: self) else { return nil }
        return self[range]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this by creating an extension for reusable next time as follow code below:**

```
extension UITextView{
    func textRangeFromNSRange(range:NSRange)->String{
        let myNSString = self.text as NSString
        return  myNSString.substring(with: range)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        if (URL.absoluteString == kURLString) {
            alert(value: textView.textRangeFromNSRange(range: characterRange))
        }
        return false
    }
```

**If you want to get value from your dictionary you can do like below:**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        if (URL.absoluteString == kURLString) {
            alert(value: dictionary[textView.textRangeFromNSRange(range: characterRange)]!)
        }
        return false
    }
```

***Noted: Make sure links in textViews are selectable but not editable.***